# How to convert a number to words in MS Excel Android app?

Tags: microsoft-excel

Excel Macros are unsupported in Android and there is also no **SpellNum Function** in Android .
I want a function which can convert a number to words.
Is there any way we can achieve this ?

eg -  40004  , should be converted to Forty Thousand Four

Answer (score -1):

The simplest approach is to use a `VLOOKUP()` table

put the number in **A1** and in **B1** enter:

```
=VLOOKUP(A1,C:D,2,FALSE)
```

[image]

Comment: But 30304 , should be printed as Thirty Thousand Three Hundred Four , how to achieve this ??